# Change GeoServer memory limits

Tags: geoserver

How to change GeoServer memory limits for [Cross-layer filter](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html#memory-limits) in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the page you link to says:

> These limits can be overridden by setting alternate values for the following parameters (**this can be done using JVM system variables, servlet context variables, or environment variables**):
>
> QUERY_LAYER_MAX_FEATURES controls the maximum number of features collected by  queryCollection
>
> GEOMETRY_COLLECT_MAX_COORDINATES controls the maximum number of coordinates collected by collectGeometries

So you can set a JVM variable by editing the startup script of your container manager (jetty or tomcat?) and looking for `JAVA_OPTS` or you can set the servlet context variables by editing the `web.xml` file or you can set the variables in your systems environment as normal.

Comment: I don't know where located startup script (jetty or tomcat)

Comment: may you write path for it?

Comment: it would depend on where you had installed it, which would depend on you knowing which one you had installed.

Comment: Geoserver installed in docker container. With Tomcat.

Comment: then you are looking for catalina.sh probably in /var/lib/tomcat/bin

Comment: I need create those variables in catalina.sh?