# How to update GeoServer memory settings?

Tags: geoserver

I am using GeoServer 2.18 under Tomcat 9.0 on CentOS 7. (It's a development environment).

I want to increase RAM of my existing GeoServer and checking following links/related questions :

https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adv_gsconfig/gsproduction.html
https://community.webfaction.com/questions/20337/how-to-limit-memory-usage-of-tomcat-geoserver
[Change GeoServer memory limits](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321087/change-geoserver-memory-limits)

It says need to update the container which is fine. I checked in catalina.sh, but not sure where  to update

How can I do this?

[image: Catalina.sh file]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the options to `CATALINA_OPTS` or `JAVA_OPTS`, the usual way to do this is to create an executable `setenv.sh` file in the same directory as `catalina.sh`.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153174/set-environment-variable-in-shell-script-access-in-tomcat-application) for more discussion.